# Modal Pop up closes automatically when button clicked(In Producation only working fine in my local)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I tried all the ways,I don't have two bootstrap files but this modal closes automatically when click on signin button.(In Producation only working fine in my local)

Issue:

you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/POoXF.jpg

Here is the code:
I have added the script for fade close after button click

```js
$('#modal-close').click(function(){
  $('#loginpop').modal('hide');
  $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
  $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
});

$('#modal-clear').click(function(){
  $('#loginpop').modal('toggle');
  $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
  $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<li><a href="" class="roundedCornersButtons" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginpop"​>signin</a></li>

<div class="modal fade" id="loginpop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div ng-include="'views/newlogin.html'"></div>
                </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer"> 
                     <div class="form-group pull-left">
                        <a href="/forgotpassword" id="modal-close" >forgotPassword</a>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                       <a href="/register" id="modal-clear">signUp</a>
                     </div> 
                 </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: When i click on `signin` the modal open and when click on `signup` modal close. so what is the problem?

Comment: @pedram when click on signin modal open and closing without entering anything

Comment: I updated your post with snippet, please see. i don't see any problem.

Comment: @pedram snippet will not hold that problem.I tried to create.The problem getting in production only it is working fine in my local environment

Comment: @pedram added screen recording and updated the question you may see there

Comment: Hmm.. so give me your live `URL` to check it `online`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157855/discussion-between-ajay-and-pedram).

Comment: test.telekha.in

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have two bootstrap files

After reviewing your codes, I realized that you included `bootstrap` script twice. One in `vendor.06e7b6f0.js` and another in `scripts.1c36a23e.js`. your modal will close at the same time you click on `signin` it kinda `display: none` or `hide()` or etc..

Remove second `Bootstrap` and try again.

Comment: I am unable to find the file in actual project folder.when run grunt serve:dist that will create the dist folder,which contains minification of the project.